# Making a successful Python HTTP POST Request

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a python script that will make a request to a desktop application listening to 8080 port. The below is the code that I use to make the request.

```
import requests 

payload = {"url":"abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz=",
"password":"qertyuioplkjhgfdsazxvnm=",
"token":"abcdefghijklmn1254786=="}

headers = {'Content-Type':'application/json'}
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9015/login',params = payload, headers=headers)
response = requests.get("http://localhost:9015/login")
print(r.status_code)
```

After making the request, I get a response code of 401.

However, when I try the same using the Postman app, I get a successful response. The following are the details I give in Postman:

```
URL: http://localhost:9015/login
METHOD : POST
Headers: Content-Type:application/json
Body: {"url":"abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz=",
       "password":"qertyuioplkjhgfdsazxvnm=",
       "token":"abcdefghijklmn1254786=="}
```

Can I get some suggestions on where I am going wrong with my python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass `params`, when you should pass `data`, or, even better, `json` for setting `Content-Type` automatically. So, it should be:

```
import json
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9015/login', data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

or

```
r = requests.post('http://localhost:9015/login', json=payload)
```

(`params` adds key-value pairs to query parameters in the url)

Comment: Thanks @alexpeits. The first option did not work for me, but the second one worked perfectly.

Comment: You're right - I have updated the first option in my answer.